# Dropbox Core API: method deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, dropbox-api

I am testing Dropbox Core API using Android Studio 0.9.2. I try to run a sample (DBRoulette) included in the dropbox sdk download and the method startAuthentication(MyActivity.this) appears deprecated. Any help or suggestion are very welcome.

Comment: Are you asking a replacement for the method or asking what deprecated method means?

Comment: I am asking a replacement for the method, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it's deprecated in favor of `startOAuth2Authentication(...)` as seen in the tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android.